# We did it at exactly the right time vs We did it at the exactly right time.

Tags: grammar, adverbs, articles, intensifying-adverbs

I know the first example is correct and I'm pretty sure the second is incorrect, but I wonder why.  So, we can say "I saw **an extremely** angry dog", but not "I saw **extremely an** angry dog."  When do we put the adverb before/after the article?

Comment: +1 Great question. Can't wait to see an answer.

Comment: Well, one is a fixed phrase and the other isn't; that's going to make a difference. As for the parallel with _an extremely_, that's not the same thing. _Exactly_ determines the correctness of the time -- essentially modifying the whole prepositional phrase _at the right time_, either from inside the phrase (_at exactly the right time_), or from right before it (_exactly at the right time_) -- whereas _extremely_ is a simple intensifier, modifying only the adjective _angry_, so it can't be moved aways from it. This doesn't say why one would want to move it, though.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, exactly modifies the adverbial phrase "the right time."  It is, thusly, an adverb modifying another adverb, which is correct.  In the second example, "the right time is the object of a preposition and must be modified by the adjective "exact" rather than the adverb "exactly."

Comment: Thank-you for your answer.  I've been thinking about it.  Is it wrong to modify the object of a preposition with an adverb?  For example: "He left without completely finishing."  In this case, "completely" seems to modify the object of the preposition "finishing".